# Can repeaters automatically use a different clientIDMode then what's set in web.config? (clientIDMode="Static")

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, clientid, asprepeater

I want to use clientIDMode="Static" in the web.config as it's awesome for front end development, obivously.

But, I'd like my repeaters, datagrids, and datalists to default to clientIDMode="Predictable" so there's not duplicate ID's on the page.  I'd prefer not to have to set this every time I create a repeater because it's extra code and if I forget I won't see any problems immediately so I'll probably continue on without realizing I made a mistake.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, i'm afraid such a thing doesn't exist.

If it's really important for you, you could implement following in your Master's or Page's `Page_Init`:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var types = new Type[] { 
        typeof(Repeater), typeof(DataGrid), typeof(GridView), 
        typeof(DataList), typeof(ListView), typeof(FormView) 
    };
    var allControls = new List<Control>();
    FindChildControlsRecursive(Page, types, allControls);
    foreach (var ctrl in allControls)
    {
        ctrl.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Predictable;
    }
}

public void FindChildControlsRecursive(Control control, IList<Type> types, IList<Control> result)
{
    foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
    {
        var controlType = childControl.GetType();
        if (typeof(Control).IsAssignableFrom(controlType) && types.Contains(controlType))
        {
            result.Add((Control)childControl);
        }
        else
        {
            FindChildControlsRecursive(childControl, types, result);
        }
    }
}
```

But in my opinion this is too much for a reminder.

Comment: Appreciate the help.  Agreed that it's not -that- important.  Thanks.